# PHP Algorithm trouble: using a "set" function for a complex object

Tags: php, algorithm

Using a set function in a class as below works great:

```
<?php

class forest
{
    public $tree;
    public function set($k, $v)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $k)) {
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}

$myClass = new forest();
$myClass->set('tree', 'birch');

?>
```

However, I can't work out how to do the same for something more complex.

```
(in pseudo-code)
tree->deciduous = birch
tree->coniferous = cypress
```

I've tried this, which didn't work:

```
<?php
class forest
{
    private $tree;
    private $climate;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->tree = new stdClass;
    }

    public function set($k, $v)
    {
        if (is_array($k)) {
            $d = $this;
            foreach ($k as $c => $b) {
                $d = $d->$b;
            }
            $d = $v;
        } else {
            if (property_exists($this, $k)) {
                $this->$k = $v;
            } else {
                echo "<pre>\n $k does not exist \n</pre>";
            }
        }
    }
}

$myClass->set('climate', 'temperate'); // << works
$myClass->set(['tree', 'deciduous'], 'birch'); // << doesn't work

?>
```

What I get for my trouble is

```
$myClass->tree ... nothing.
```

I can't wrap my head around why this wouldn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you update your post and show us your expected output for `$myClass->set(['tree', 'deciduous'], 'birch');`? It seems your `$this->tree = new stdClass;` is being used either further down the code

Answer (score 1):

This feels like an anti-OOP pattern. I'm not saying it is wrong, but classes are generally used to represent static things. To deeply set something using your code, we're pretty much left to `stdClass` to represent the specific object to hold properties. So for instance, `deciduous` has to be an instance of `stdClass` because we want to give it a value, and also assign it to something. I think ideally an array would be used for this.

That said, this code should do what you are looking for. I wrapped it into a trait just to make it more portable across other classes, but that's not strictly necessary. It is close to your original code, at least in spirit, but I removed the `property_exists` check.

```php
trait Setter {
    public function set(array|string $k, $v) {
        if(!is_array($k)){
            $k = [$k];
        }
        
        $last = array_pop($k);
        $obj = $this;
        while($k){
            $item = array_shift($k);
            $obj->$item = new stdClass();
            $obj = $obj->$item;
        }
        
        $obj->$last = $v;
    }
}

class forest
{
    use Setter;
    
    private $tree;
    private $climate;
}

$myClass = new forest();
$myClass->set('climate', 'temperate'); // << works
$myClass->set(['tree', 'deciduous'], 'birch'); // << doesn't work

var_dump($myClass);
```

This kicks out:

```php
object(forest)#1 (2) {
  ["tree":"forest":private]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["deciduous"]=>
    string(5) "birch"
  }
  ["climate":"forest":private]=>
  string(9) "temperate"
}
```

You can see a demo of it here: https://3v4l.org/EFfa2#v8.0.14

**Edit**

Thinking about this more, it has a feeling of attempting to model infinite-depth hierarchical database content. At a certain point, you have to decide the value of having object represent things, or if we're really just "tagging" things. I could be wrong about your usage, too, but I just wanted to throw another way out there.

This version uses to classes, one for the `forest` and one for a `tree`. A `tree` is a very simple object that has a single property of `name` which would map to `Silver Birch`, for intsance.

The `forest` also has a single property, `trees`, that is an array of the possible types, with the last item being an instance of a `tree`.

```php
class tree
{
    public function __construct(public string $name){}
}

class forest
{
    public array $trees = [];
    public function addTree(string $name, string|array $types): void
    {
        if(!is_array($types)){
            $types = [$types];
        }
        
        $last = &$this->trees;
        foreach($types as $type) {
            if(!array_key_exists($type, $last)){
                $last[$type] = [];
            }
            $last = &$last[$type];
        }
        $last[] = new tree($name);
    }
}

$myClass = new forest();
$myClass->addTree('silver', ['deciduous', 'birch']);
$myClass->addTree('river', ['deciduous', 'birch']);
var_dump($myClass);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/LALFp#v8.0.14

There is unfortunately a problem with this:

```
$myClass->addTree('maple', ['deciduous']);
```

That actually works, however when evaluating the `trees` array you'd probably have to check the key to determine if it is an integer or a string to determine if this is a sub-type or a category. But that's getting into the weeds.